# copying elements from vector to another one

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I have two vectors of pointers: `arr` that contains some elements already and `temp`, the new vector I want to copy specific elements from `arr` to. For example I'd like to copy second element of `arr` to be copied into `temp` and deleted from `arr`. How can it be done?

I tried this, but it's not good:

```
void deleteobject(vector < figure3d *> &arr,int index,vector < figure3d *> &temp)
{
     vector < figure3d * > :: iterator i=arr.begin();
     temp.insert(temp.begin(),*i);
     delete *i;
     arr.erase(i);
     temp[0]->print();
}
```

Comment: whats not good about it?

Comment: If you are inserting in the beginning of the vector too often, then you should consider changing it to a deque.

Comment: Doug T - how said that is not good ?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't `delete` the object you're copying since you want to keep it in `temp` -  just `erase` it from `arr`.

Comment: it work thanksssssssss
but dont i hold a memory and not using it ?
could it be a problem ?

Answer (score 0):

`arr.begin()` gives you an iterator pointing to the first element, so if you want the second element, you should advance `i` one:

```
++i;
```

If you want the `index`th element, you should advance `i` by `index`:

```
i += index;
```

Storing raw pointers in a vector, and having to remember to delete them when removing them from the vector is a memory leak waiting to happen. And ass molbdnilo mentioned in another answer, you actually have a memory handling error since you're deleting the object that temp has a pointer to.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to copy an element at specified index (argument `index`) and remove it from vector `temp`. This function could look simple like this:

```
void deleteobject(std::vector<figure3d*> &arr, int index, std::vector<figure3d*> &temp)
{
    temp.insert(temp.begin(), arr[index]);
    arr.erase(arr.begin() + index);
}
```

In this case, you don't copy the object itself, but only a reference to it - thus you don't need to free the memory where this object is stored.

Also note that in your function you call `delete *i;` which frees the memory where the object pointed by `i` is stored - and the pointer that stored in `arr` becomes invalid (**dangling pointer**), because it points to memory that was freed already.

And I also suggest you to use vector of objects rather than vector of pointers to objects - although elements get copied, it's usually fast enough and there is no troublesome memory management connected with it. And in case there is a good reason why you use vector of pointers ( [When to use pointers in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2169322/1168156) ), 
I suggest you to use vector of  smart pointers instead: if you have TR1 or C++11 support, use `std::shared_ptr`, otherwise use `boost::shared_ptr` ( [Where is shared_ptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2918202/1168156) )

Comment: it work thanksssssssss but dont i hold a memory and not using it ? could it be a problem ?

Comment: @AsafShay: In this case, you don't copy the object itself, but only a reference to it - thus you don't need to free the memory where this object is stored.

Comment: i understand .tanks you all for the help.i dealing with that for hours .again tanks all

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for !
something like this is what I would do:

```
Class removePredicate{
Public: 
    bool operator() (figure3d** item) {
       //remove logic goes here
    }
};

remove_copy_if(arr.begin(), arr.end(), back_inserter(tmp), not1(removePredicate));
```

This will copy all the elements that you want to remove into tmp. The to actually remove them from arr it's just a simple application of the remove-erase idiom:

```
erase(remove_if(arr.begin(), arr.end(), not1(removePredicate)), arr.end());
```

There's probably a way to combine these two steps into one line but you run the risk of losing readability at point.